# Lightning Data Service to clear Lookup field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup, update, data-service

Using the LDS native functionality we can modify the contents of a lookup field using a `lightning:inputfield` element, however clearing the field out and saving has no effect. See the inputfield assigned to **ContactId** on Cases below.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">

<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  mode="EDIT"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
                  />

<div class="slds-box">
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                              objectApiName="Case" >
        <div>
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                <lightning:layoutItem >
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" />
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
        </div>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ContactId" />
        <lightning:button type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>
```

Are there any workarounds to this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

One thought is to give the inputFields an `aura:id` so you can attach a change event handler where you have a custom function that evaluates truthiness and clears out the value by hand.

That's a bit heavy handed, but I've used onchange handlers on `force` namespaced components because their internal change event wasnt behaving as expected.

This might be the same case?